# 7-Zip command to create and extract a password-protected ZIP file on Windows?

Tags: windows, encryption, command-line, zip, 7zip

On Mac/Linux to zip/unzip password protected zip files, I use:
Zip:

```
zip -P password -r encrypted.zip folderIWantToZip
```

Unzip:

```
unzip -P password encrypted.zip
```

What are the equivalent command on Windows on the command line (assuming that 7zip has been installed)?

I have been doing research and found that it is not possible to password encrypt using the Java zip4j library. Also Windows does not have a zip command prompt like Mac/Linux

Comment: http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/syntax.htm

Comment: Your last sentence suggests that you might actually be wanting to do this from Java, which would be a programming question.  But the question you actually asked is not, and belongs on SuperUser.

Comment: googlers... →please stop putting _any_ trust in zip password „protection“. It is **not**. – consider 7zip or maybe rar.

Comment: Using `-P` is a security vulnerability on multi-user operating systems. It is recommended to use `-e` instead.

Answer (score 167):

From http://www.dotnetperls.com:

```
7z a secure.7z * -pSECRET
```

Where:

```
7z        : name and path of 7-Zip executable
a         : add to archive
secure.7z : name of destination archive
*         : add all files from current directory to destination archive
-pSECRET  : specify the password "SECRET"
```

To open :

```
7z x secure.7z
```

Then provide the SECRET password

***Note:***
*If the password contains spaces or special characters, then enclose it with single quotes*

```
7z a secure.7z * -p"pa$$word @|"
```

Comment: is it possible to provide the secret password when opening such that it can all be done as one command? I dont have a windows machine to test it currently

Comment: with a redirection: < you should be able to store the passwd in a file and launch the command like 7z x secure.7z < passwd.txt

Comment: great, I just implemented something just now using [RoboTask Lite](http://robotask.com/) to upload to the cloud (welll 7zip a file to a local folder, that is cloud synced) - by clicking a tray icon using these parameters. Before I was manually 7zipping, and getting very annoyed and having to rename files

Comment: The example password in the final note on the command line is actually a bad choice since `$$` inside double quoted will extract to the current process id. Thus you pretty much don't know which password you gave. Same with single `$` which will treat the following characters as a variable name and most likely will be empty. Use single quotes instead like `-p 'pa$$word...'

Comment: The last example doesn't work on windows because `'` is also included on the password and to make it work, I'd to use double quotes `"`

Comment: I tried this and it created a regular archive that was not password protected.

Comment: That's strange... Did you provide the password as indicated ? or just try 7z a secure.7z * -p and you'll be prompted for a passwd

Comment: 'then enclose it with single quotes' and you use regular quotes

Comment: It works as it should :-) Big thanks!

Comment: It's better to let terminal/console to ask you for the password to make sure special characters are captured without issues `7z a -p secure.7z *`

Comment: yeah sure, but it's up to you if you want to provide passwd in commandline or not, thanks !

Answer (score 47):

**General Syntax:**

```
7z a archive_name target parameters
```

Check your 7-Zip dir. Depending on the release you have, **7z** may be replaced with **7za** in the syntax.

**Parameters:**

- **-p** encrypt and prompt for PW.
- **-pPUT_PASSWORD_HERE** (this replaces **-p**) if you want to preset the PW with no prompt.
- **-mhe=on** to hide file structure, otherwise file structure and names will be visible by default.

Eg. This will prompt for a PW and hide file structures:

```
7z a archive_name target -p -mhe=on
```

Eg. No prompt, visible file structure:

```
7z a archive_name target -pPUT_PASSWORD_HERE
```

And so on. If you leave **target** blank, 7z will assume * in current directory and it will recurs directories by default.

Comment: Same command structure works on linux if anyone wants to know.

Answer (score 14):

To fully script-automate:

**Create:**

```
7z -mhc=on -mhe=on -pPasswordHere a %ZipDest% %WhatYouWantToZip%
```

**Unzip:**

```
7z x %ZipFile% -pPasswordHere
```

(Depending, you might need to: Set Path=C:\Program Files\7-Zip;%Path% )

Comment: What does mhc do?

Comment: @scrollout according to 7Zip doc "Enables or disables archive header compressing. The default mode is hc=on. If archive header compressing is enabled, the archive header will be compressed with LZMA method. "

Answer (score 1):

I'm maybe a little bit late but I'm currently trying to develop a program which can brute force a password protected zip archive. First I tried all commands I found in the internet to extract it through cmd... But it never worked....Every time I tried it, the cmd output said, that the key was wrong but it was right. I think they just disenabled this function in a current version.

What I've done to Solve the problem was to download an older 7zip version(4.?) and to use this for extracting  through cmd.

This is the command: 
"C:/Program Files (86)/old7-zip/7z.exe" x -pKey "C:/YOURE_ZIP_PATH"

The first value("C:/Program Files (86)/old7-zip/7z.exe") has to be the path where you have installed the old 7zip to. The x is for extract and the -p For you're password. Make sure you put your password without any spaces behind  the -p! The last value is your zip archive to extract. The destination where the zip is extracted to will be the current path of cmd. You can change it with:  cd YOURE_PATH

Now I let execute this command through java with my password trys. Then I check the error output stream of cmd and if it is null-> then the password is right!

Comment: general info: if you need to download the 7z program then download it from here
https://www.7-zip.org/download.html
it will default install it here:
C:\Program Files\7-Zip