# PowerShell command only works without spaces between arguments

Tags: powershell

I try certain source codes using PowerShell to extract an password protected archive using 7zip:

This command doesn' work (7zip is an alias for $7zipPath):

```
& 7zip x "$zipFile" -o "$output" -p $zipFilePassword
```

### I get the this error:
Command Line Error:
Too short switch:

But when I remove the spaces between the variables -o and -p, the archive can be extracted. This behaviour confuses me with other command line tools like git etc.? Why is it so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28160254/7-zip-command-to-create-and-extract-a-password-protected-zip-file-on-windows

Answer (score 1):

The **behavior is specific to 7-Zip (`7z.exe`)** and applies to whatever program (shell) you invoke it from:

Deviating from widely used conventions observed by CLIs such as `git`, **`7z` requires that even switches (options) that have *mandatory* arguments, such as `-o` and `-p`, have the argument *directly attached* to the switch name** - no spaces are allowed:

```
& 7zip x $zipFile -o"$output" -p"$zipFilePassword"
```

Note that you normally need *not* enclose variable references in PowerShell in `"..."` (note how `$zipFile` isn't), even if they contain spaces. However, in order to attach them directly to switch names, you do.

Alternatively, you could enclose the entire token - switch name *and* argument - in double quotes:

```
& 7zip x $zipFile "-o$output" "-p$zipFilePassword"
```